# Как сделать подзаголовок в WordPress без плагина

Tags: wordpress

С плагином любой может, а вот хочется разобраться в этом самому, как добавлять подзаголовки и, возможно, другие дополнительные поля с помощью functions.php буду очень признателен за ссылки или функции с методами.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_740/blok-proizvolnyih-poley-v-adminke-wordpress-svoimi-rukami.html

Comment: Если эти поля - для сайта, а не для конкретной темы, то лучше это делать не в файле функций, а плагинами. Заодно и научишься их писать. Тут вообще ничего сложного - просто оформить тот же код в виде файла. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0